# Group_by does not change the results when it is combined with bi_class function in r

Tags: r, dplyr

The code below is grouping the data by ProjectID and creates a binary classification of the svi and race_black variables using the "quantile" method and 3 categories. The problem with the code is that the bi_class function returns exactly the same results when the group_by function is included vs when it is not.

```
 IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  dplyr::arrange(ProjectID, Zip) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ProjectID) %>%
  #svi+black project
  bi_class(x = svi,
           y = race_black,
           style = "quantile",
           dim = 3) %>%
  mutate() %>%
   dplyr::rename(bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your data so we can help with this? Also, your call of `mutate` doesn’t do anything in this code

Comment: Should we presume your `bi_class` function is the one that comes from the `biscale` package?

Comment: I don't think `bi_class` was written to observe groupings within the data frame it receives, so you may need an approach that splits or nests the data before the `bi_class` step is applied separately to each grouping.

Comment: Yes, bi_class comes from biscale package. I think this code should work: 

IDD_nhmap <- IDD_nhmap %>%
  dplyr::arrange(ProjectID, Zip) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(., ProjectID) %>%
  #svi+black project
  do(bi_class(., keep_factors=TRUE, x = svi,
           y = race_black,
           style = "quantile",
           dim = 3)) %>%
   dplyr::rename(bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class)